# What's a good tool for creating .epub format e-books?

Tags: software-recommendation, ebooks, epub

I have seen a  question here about reading .epub but I would like to create my own easily from a GUI, what is available for Ubuntu? Even if I have to download something outside the repository, as long as it installs easily and works well, I would also like the software to be able to support the use of .svg images and tables.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### [Sigil](https://github.com/Sigil-Ebook/Sigil)

[image: screenshots]

This is an excellent program for creating .epub files, works almost like a word processor

After a lot of frustration with other applications I can say this one works, has good support for .svg images and tables just code your tables as xhtml, it can easily import an existing .epub too.

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/)?

[image]

I'm not sure about the images, but I know that it converts formats very well, and as a bonus, works with my Nook.

Comment: I nearly thought you meant the KOffice suite - you should point out that Calibre here is not the new KOffice =). Looks useful though ^^.

Comment: Sorry about that.  It's quite useful; I've converted plenty of PDFs for my Nook with it.

Comment: Calibre is a nice tool, unfortunately when converting either .odt or .pdf with vector images I do not get what I want, no images just a blue question mark for images in .odt and nothing for images in .pdf, I would have to manually edit the .epub, somethingI do not want to do. Thanks anyway calibre does well converting text based books, a partial solution.

Comment: Sorry it's not working for you.  I don't think there's anything that really works well for images.  Glad I can help you get to a partial solution though.

Answer (score 5):

I'm listing a couple of options that I've installed and used. I'm not sure of the extent of svg support, but I believe there is svg import support.  Sigil is the one I'd try first.  ecub is free but not open source.  Jutoh is commercial (though inexpensive if I recall, and it has a trial mode for the first 20 docs), but it might be worth looking at just because of its interesting implementation (not necessarily a knock against it).  It is supposed to be feature-rich, though I found it too slow on my machine at the time.

[Sigil -- A WYSIWYG ebook editor.](http://code.google.com/p/sigil/)
[Jutoh -- "epublishing made easy"](http://www.jutoh.com/)

[image]

As was mentioned before, Calibre can also work at bridging formats.  It isn't designed as an editor, just a converter, but I've used it successfully for simple documents with straightforward graphical elements.

Answer (score 2):

Atlantis Word Processor:
http://www.atlantiswordprocessor.com/en/videos/creating_ebooks_introduction

It is a Windows software. But you can run it on Ubuntu:
http://www.atlantiswordprocessor.com/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1753

Comment: While running Windows software is possible in Ubuntu (Wine, Virtual Box, VMware), Linux software is preferred. Is there a  Linux equivalent?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no Linux version.

Answer (score 1):

Scrivener, in my humble opinion, is the quintessential drafting tool. It can compile to .epub, .mobi, and .ps for publication.

<s>It does not support images.</s>

It does support images (edited Thursday, July 17, 2014 04:25 PM).

Latest:
http://www.literatureandlatte.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=28194&sid=6425911690d37150021ef7fc19d88a1c

#### Scrivener Interface on Ubuntu KDE

[image]

#### Scrivener Image in Document Support

[image]

#### Scrivener Document Format Support

[image]

#### Scrivener Book Syle Support

[image]

### Scrivener is Trial Software

[image]

Comment: Is it electron based application?