# Is there any application for Ubuntu to create ebooks?

Tags: software-recommendation, ebooks

Like MAC has ibooks author for preparing ebooks, are there any applications for Ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a good tool for creating .epub format e-books?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22936/whats-a-good-tool-for-creating-epub-format-e-books)

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can check  an application named sigil

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rgibert/ebook
```

Step 2 : Next, run the following command in the terminal to update your Ubuntu system.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Step 3 : Finally, run the following command in the terminal to install Sigil 0.6.0 on your Ubuntu system.

```
$ sudo apt-get install sigil
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) With that you can convert many file formats (like pdf) to epub and other ebook formats.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LibreOffice.

To create ebooks in the format **ePub** (`.epub`), you can install the extension [Writer2ePub](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/project/Writer2ePub). There is one [tutorial (in Spanish)](http://www.atareao.es/ubuntu/crear-tu-propio-ebook-con-libreoffice-en-formato-epub/); when I find one in English I'll put the link here.

To create ebooks in the format **FictionBook** (`.fb2`), you can use the extension [FBTools](http://www.fbtools.org/). They have [a tutorial](http://www.fbtools.org/home/creating-e-books-with-ooo-fbtools) and the download comes with templates (in Russian, but you only need to pay attention to the style).

Finally, you can make an ebook in **PDF**. Just make sure to structure properly your book, so you can have usable table of contents, indices, references to figures, tables and equations (with hyperlinks and everything). There are several tutorials and templates. I just found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53WxwwOPg58), but I'm sure you can find better ones.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not call ibooks author  ebook creation software. It is a proprietary tool for creating ebooks which work only in the Apple ibooks program.

I have not played with it in a while, but I've been told that Sigil is the best cross-platform GUI epub creator. http://www.ubuntugeek.com/sigil-the-epub-editor.html